# acer aspire E1-422 Insyde h20 BIOS advance settings

Tags: virtualbox, bios, acer-aspire

I bought acer aspire E1 422 AMD laptop MFG:on 2013/12/03
Its MAD V technology to be used as virtual machine.

But the bios(Insyde H20 EFI 3.7  ver 2.7 ) have been disabled to change the VT settings

How to enable acer aspire E1-422 Insyde h20 BIOS advance settings?
I have been goggling for weeks long, but it confusing for me what to do & how to do.

Is there any way out to flash mentioned bios to enable AMD V technology?
can virtualbox handle bios settings?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That BIOS is pitiful as far as finding the VB setting like in any other PC and OS.

I have been looking in that BIOS and I see no mention of VirtualBox, not to mention I have to start over with F10+Enter+Del over and over again.

It is my only bad PC from a store, my other 6 computers had no problem with this.